# Determine the point in Quadrant 2 where the line $y= -3x$ interects the unit circle.

Tags: trigonometry

Determine the point in Quadrant 2 where the line $y= -3x$ interects the unit circle.

How do I determine the points when given the equation?

Comment: Do you know what the equation of the unit circle is? If so do you know when two curves intersect?

Comment: Use x^2+y^2=1 as second equation for circle and solve that system

Comment: How do I set it up?

Comment: If you are familiar with those concepts, then I'd advise just drawing a diagram. That should show you what to do.

Comment: Have you tried graphing the unit circle, $y^2 + y^2 = 1$, or the line $y=-3x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find the point $(x,y)$ satisfying

$$x^2+y^2=1$$
and
$$y=-3x$$

Substitute second one into the first to obtain

$$x^2+(-3x)^2=1 \iff 10x^2=1 \iff x=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt {10}}$$

Since you're in the second quadrant, we have $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt {10}}$. Substitute this into $y=-3x$ to obtain

$$(x,y)=\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt {10}}, \frac{3}{\sqrt {10}}\right)$$